# Gulp pipe one file at a time

Tags: asynchronous, callback, gulp, synchronization

Not 100% sure if this is an antipattern or not, but what I want to do is pipe one single file at a time through my gulp task, and have it run through a custom written module.

What I have is a gulp task that'll craw through multiple directories within a folder and pipe through JSON files in the gulp task.

```
gulp.task('guideBuilder', function(){
    gulp.src('content/*/*/*/*/*.json') //access the json in the folders
        .pipe(customParser()) //parse through and grab the information you need
        .pipe(rename({extname: '.json'}))
        .pipe(prettify(4))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('content/json/parsed'))
});
```

What happens is gulp breaks down because the files are being passed though my function is async, however it works when I pass in the direct path to the file. Meaning that the function works, and I think what I need to do is have it somehow run sync or pass a single file through at a time.